# Why is the Higgs boson important?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, higgs

I saw this in many books and I just wanted to know why is it important to us... I know it is something related to the Higgs field but what is it? For over a century why do physicists wanted to find that particle... An explanation of 2-3 lines would be more than enough

Comment: Detecting the Higgs particle is something you predict if the Higgs field exists and the Brout-Englert-Higgs mechanism is true. By the way: People did not look for it for over a century. It was introduced in the 1960's.

Comment: ... not sure why this was so merrily downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

The Higgs boson is important because it explains (among other things) why the W and Z gauge bosons have mass and so why the [weak force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction) has a very small range, unlike the closely related electromagnetic force. The Higgs boson was hypothesised by Peter Higgs and others in 1964 (so physicists have only been looking it for just over half a century, not for over a century) and it had been incorporated into the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. The detection of the Higgs boson was an important direct experimental confirmation that this part of the Standard Model is correct.

For more details see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson).

Comment: One should separate the boson from the field.  Finding a Higgs boson was important . showing that the higgs mechanism dependent on the Higgs field followed the rest of the QFT of the standard model. There were theories  that made the same effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor_(physics)  that are dismissed by finding the boson.